# How to know if login is repeated with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have the entity `Users` with `idUser`, `login` and `password` and when I want to insert a new `User` I need to check if `login` is repeated. Actually I'm doing this:

```
public boolean existsLogin(final String login) {
        Criteria crit = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(
                User.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("login", login));
        User user = (User) crit.uniqueResult();
        return user.getLogin() == null;
    }
```

But I think that I can do more efficient, and this, actually throws NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for NullPointerException, is that in case you have no such login in DB. then the unique result will return `null`.

To solve that you can just check that result is not null

`return null != crit.uniqueResult();`

Answer (score 0):

Like Damian says, your problem is on the uniqueResult() that returns you null.

Anyway, to do what you want to do you can, too, take these approachs:

1- If login column is UNIQUE in your DDBB you can try to insert it and catch the exception that, if that login exists, will throw the DDBB...

The exception will be an SQLException and  SQLException.getSQLState() will give you a code:"23000" will indicate a unique constraint violation in at least MySQL, PostgreSQL, and Oracle.

2- You can, also, make a simple HQL/SQL select and execute it:

```
session.createSQLQuery("select count(1) as cnt from my_table where login=:login")
.setParameter("login", login).uniqueResult();
```

That should be, in a general case, more eficient because the returned value will be an integer and not a full object that must be build and mantained in memory.